# MarketplaceSearchTask special chars ( ä ü o ) not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, marketplace

what kind of encoding does the marketplacesearchtask expect?

```
MarketplaceSearchTask marketplaceSearchTask = new MarketplaceSearchTask();
marketplaceSearchTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Music;
marketplaceSearchTask.SearchTerms = "äöü";
marketplaceSearchTask.Show();
```

This results in a search like "Â⃞Ô⃞Û⃞".

Can someone help me with please?

Comment: How did you encode this source file?

Comment: sourcefile: default encoding of Visual Studio Express for WP (dunno where i can check this)

The reason i found this error was because I read a document from an API. I use streamreader with UTF8 for this. But setting the SearchTerms to this string also results in this strange characters. And parsing UTF8 to Unicode using Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, arr); results in the same characters. In a textblock or textbox everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only limitation on **SearchTerms** is that it be non-null and non-empty. Whether you find anything in the marketplace given those values is another question all together.